# How to append JSON array with specific data

Tags: json, ansible

I am trying to run :

```
- name: Describe config aggregator
  shell: >
    aws configservice describe-configuration-aggregators --configuration-aggregator-name test-config
  register: config_ouput
```

below is the data generated.

```
    {
        "ConfigurationAggregators": [
            {
                "ConfigurationAggregatorName": "test-config",
                "ConfigurationAggregatorArn": "arn:aws:config:us-east-1:4567:config-aggregator/config-aggregator-uw2o9pzf",
                "AccountAggregationSources": [
                    {
                        "AccountIds": [
                            "895677"
                        ],
                        "AllAwsRegions": true
                    }
                ],
                "CreationTime": 1624454176.124,
                "LastUpdatedTime": 1626426755.504
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now I want to append the accountIds above with any new account say 1234567 which should give me result such as

```
{
    "ConfigurationAggregators": [
        {
            "ConfigurationAggregatorName": "test-config",
            "ConfigurationAggregatorArn": "arn:aws:config:us-east-1:8778:config-aggregator/test-config-pzf",
            "AccountAggregationSources": [
                {
                    "AccountIds": [
                        "895677,1234567"
                    ],
                    "AllAwsRegions": true
                }
            ],
            "CreationTime": 1624454176.124,
            "LastUpdatedTime": 1626426755.504
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to do is:

```
- name: Export results to JSON
  set_fact:
    config_ouput_json: "{{ config_ouput + [{"AccountIds": "1234567","AllAwsRegions": true}]}}"
```

but this doesn't work, please let me know the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you require bit of JSON manipulation to achieve your task.

**Steps :**

1. Store output of first command in some json file. In your case you can keep that as registered variable of ansible.
2. Get existing `account_ids` in some variable.
3. Create a `list` of new accounts as variables in ansible.
4. Iterate over new account_ids and add to existing account_ids.
5. Update the aws config command.

**Sample Code :**

```
- name: initial validation
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    newAccountIds:
      - "123456"
      - "566544"
      - "555445"

  tasks:
  - name: register json file
    include_vars:
      file: 'abc.json'
      name: bundle

  - name: set value
    set_fact:
      values: "{{ bundle['ConfigurationAggregators'][0]['AccountAggregationSources'][0]['AccountIds'] }}"

  - set_fact:
      values: "{{ (values | default([])) + [item] }}"
    with_items: "{{ newAccountIds }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ values }}"

  - debug:
      msg: '"aws configservice put-configuration-aggregator --configuration-aggregator-name test-config --account-aggregation-sources "[{"AccountIds": {{ values | to_json }},"AwsRegions": ["us-east-1"]}]\""'
```

**Sample Output :**

```
PLAY [initial validation] ********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [register json file] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set value] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=123456)
ok: [localhost] => (item=566544)
ok: [localhost] => (item=555445)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "895677",
        "123456",
        "566544",
        "555445"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": "\"aws configservice put-configuration-aggregator --configuration-aggregator-name test-config --account-aggregation-sources \"[{\"AccountIds\": [\"895677\", \"123456\", \"566544\", \"555445\"],\"AwsRegions\": [\"us-east-1\"]}]\\\"\""}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Hi Shubh,

Till debug it was ok, but when i putting this to implement on the server, it throws me error.
any idea what will be the current syntax then? it says command not found.

- name: Configure config aggregator
  shell: >
    'aws configservice put-configuration-aggregator --configuration-aggregator-name test-config --account-aggregation-sources "[{"AccountIds": {{ values | to_json }},"AllAwsRegions": true}]"'

Comment: /bin/sh: aws configservice put-configuration-aggregator --configuration-aggregator-name RDS-details-test --account-aggregation-sources "[{"AccountIds": ["895677", "123456", "555445"],"AllAwsRegions": true}]": command not found

Comment: correct syntax should be 
aws configservice put-configuration-aggregator --configuration-aggregator-name MyAggregator --account-aggregation-sources "[{\"AccountIds\": [\"AccountID1\",\"AccountID2\",\"AccountID3\"],\"AllAwsRegions\": true}]"

I feel cz of "\" missing it is throwing this error.

Comment: Can this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580797/how-to-escape-backslash-and-double-quote-in-ansible-script-module

Comment: this doesn't works for me, i was even thinking what if we append only AccountIDs in aggregatorsource and then save the file as json on remote, use it for deploying it then.

I have even asked the question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68812442/trying-to-append-a-json/68813287?noredirect=1#comment121617338_68813287 
you have any clue to this? I cannot use ansible 2.10