# Trying to append a json

Tags: json, ansible

When a new account is added, it should be added in the below structure

```
- name: Describe config aggregator
  shell: >
    aws configservice describe-configuration-aggregators --configuration-aggregator-name test-config
   register: config_output
- debug: msg="{{ config_output.stdout | from_json }}"
```

output:

```
        "ConfigurationAggregators": [
            {
                "ConfigurationAggregatorArn": "arn:aws:config:us-east-1:4424:config-aggregator/config-aggregator-uw",
                "CreationTime": 1624454176.124,
                "ConfigurationAggregatorName": "test-config",
                "AccountAggregationSources": [
                    {
                        "AllAwsRegions": true,
                        "AccountIds": [
                            "80570",
                            "17622"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "LastUpdatedTime": 1629115098.532
            }
        ]
```

I have stored only preferred data in a variable:

```
- name: Export results to JSON
  set_fact:
    bundle: "{{ config_output.stdout | from_json }}"
- name: set value
  set_fact:
    values: "{{ bundle['ConfigurationAggregators'][0]['AccountAggregationSources'] }}"
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "AccountIds": [
            "80570",
            "17622"
        ],
        "AllAwsRegions": true
    }
]
```

I want to add '78956' in AccountIds, for this I am using below syntax.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ values | combine(to_append, recursive=True, list_merge='append') }}"
```

but this give me error
`"msg": "'recursive' is the only valid keyword argument"`

I have stored the to_append as a var already just like mentioned in below comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ansible >= 2.10, you can define an element having the same structure as your original one with the missing list element and use the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) with its `recursive` and `list_merge` options.

**Note:** this is a bit quickNdirty and might have some side effects if your input structure changes (e.g. several element in the top level list....). For a better / more accurate answer, you should describe your real use case and how you plan to use this transformed structure (loop, template, write to file...).

The following example playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your example var on a single line for legibility
    Variables: [{"Strings":["abc","xyz"],"Inputs":true}]

    # This what we will append to the above structure
    to_append:
      - Strings:
          - efg

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Variables | combine(to_append, recursive=true, list_merge='append') }}"
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "Inputs": true,
        "Strings": [
            "abc",
            "xyz",
            "efg"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I got this error post running it
   "msg": "'recursive' is the only valid keyword argument",

Comment: It's important to mention that *Variable* is a list. The filter [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) ``can also take multiple arguments to merge``. This means all items in the list *Variable* will be combined with *to_append*. This might be expected or not.

Comment: @AniK you are using ansible <=2.9. The `list_merge` option needs ansible >= 2.10. I just edited my answer to add that precision.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.
You have any idea on what other syntax can be used here, since i cannot upgrade ansible.

Comment: @AniK Please see my note and edit your question. I have tons of possible solutions but I have absolutely no idea which one correctly applies to a situation you don't clearly describe.

Comment: And as a side note, upgrading ansible can be as simple as `pip install --upgrade ansible` for a normal unix user. So make sure you are not trying to work around a constraint which does not exist if the above actually suits your needs.

Comment: Provided you with exact use case. might help you more.

Comment: Not really. I don't understand which data you want to use in the end, from which intermediate var, if you are going to loop on it or send it at once, from which task, using which ansible module...

Comment: let's assume we have above json, i just want the way to append in 2.9 and not 2.10.
Cannot upgrade it to ansible.
the method you have told, do you have any other way around please for 2.9.

Comment: for Ansible 2.9 or lower, this can be used.
https://serverfault.com/questions/1074918/append-json-dictonaries/1074920#1074920